# Does the ASUS U36SG wifi card support packet injection?

Tags: wireless-networking, packet-injection

The title basically says it all; does the integrated wireless networking card in ASUS U36SG support packet injection? It has an Intel HM65 Express chipset, but I've been unable to find out if it has injection support..

Please note that I want to know because I'm considering buying one, if I already had one it would be an easy thing to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the opportunity to actually test it I found that Asus U36SG does indeed support Packet Injection, and so do, of course, Asus U31SG and all other laptops using the Intel HM65 Express chipset.